Is "take a profit" correct in this sentence? "take profit" vs "take a profit" across centuries
Mandelbrot writes in chapter XII of The Misbehavior of Markets: A Fractal View of Financial Turbulence:

Suppose big news has inflated a stock price by 40 percent in a week, more than twice its normal volatility. What are the odds that, anytime soon, yet another 40 percent run will occur? Not impossible, of course, but certainly not large. A prudent investor would do as the Wall Street pros: Take a profit.

I am aware that profit is both countable and uncountable noun. I haven't come  across take a profit. anywhere else. Ngrams show that the latter was more prevalent than take profit for some time between 1760s and 1980s.
1. Is A prudent investor would do as the Wall Street pros: Take a profit. correct?
2. What is the difference in meaning between take profit and take a profit and in what context could the latter be correctly used?
3. Has there been described any change of usage of indefinite article in the history of English that explains the period of 1760-1880 on the chart. I would love to come across more examples of such usage. Where might I read more about it?

This is just how "a" works in English: "a profit" means a particular instance of money you make from an individual transaction, and to "take a profit" is to extract or go home with such a sum of money; "profit" without an article means money gained in general. Your NGram seems a red herring. Google finds plenty instances of "take a profit"; the first for me is from the FT: As the old saying goes, “it's never wrong to take a profit”. Seems a solid source.

At the bottom of the NGrams page are links to specific examples of "take profit" and "take a profit". A lot of them look garbage. Some use "take profit" to mean gain something non-financial e.g. to receive moral uplift or education. NGram isn't magic; it's full of badly-OCRed documents that have been randomly selected for little reason and are often mis-dated, and you need to look at the sources.

There are about six times (~18 million) as many hits on Google for "take a profit" as for "take profit" (~6 million) according to the data I see. Also, Google ngrams show the same recent trend (though the greater popularity of 'take a profit' has only been consistent since about 1990). But one has to be careful not to put too much weight on the accuracy and an individual interpretation of such claimed data.
For instance, there are various complications in that 'take profit' in particular is used in ways not paralleled by 'take a profit'.
But 'take a profit' is idiomatic for the usage here. Compare 'take a loss' / 'take a hit', where the indefinite article is not optional in normal use. Dictionaries class these two expressions as idioms, hence fixed phrases.


take a profit:

On the other hand, a take-profit point is the price at which a trader will sell a stock and take a profit on the
trade.

[Investopedia]


take a loss [idiom]: to lose money

They took a loss on the deal.

[Merriam-Webster]


take a hit: to suffer heavy losses or be badly affected (by something)†....

Our team will take a hit if the ban on athletes from other countries is maintained by the state athletics association.

[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms]
† 'Take a hit' can certainly have the sense of being damaged and therefore less able to function, compete, or fight, but I've heard it used in the sense of 'accept an inevitable reverse (so one can get on with the vitally important matters regardless).
